# If $A$ is $n$ by $m$ matrix and $B$ is $m$ by $p$ matrix, show that $\left |A B\right |\leq m\left |A\right |\left |B\right |$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

**Problem:** If $A$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix, and $B$ is an $m$ by $p$ matrix, show that $$\left |A B\right |\leq m\left |A\right |\left |B\right |,$$
where $$|A|=\max\{|a_{ij}|: {1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}\}.$$

**My Attempt:** For any $i=1,2,...,n$ and $j=1,2,...,p$, we have

$$\left| \sum ^{m}_{k=1}a_{ik}b_{kj}\right|\leq \sum ^{m}_{k=1}\left |a_{ik}b_{kj}\right |\leq \ ??? $$ I couldn't continue, can you help?

Comment: Which norm are you using?

Comment: @cmk We don't use norm. Edited question

Comment: What do you mean by $|A|$?

Comment: @copper.hat I actually i dont know, this question is from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds Chapter 1

Comment: I am sure that Munkres has supplied a definition somewhere...

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet it's specified on page 5 (a few lines above the theorem that you're trying to prove is first stated). I'd suggest editing this into your question.

Comment: @cmk I saw page 5, you are right.

Comment: @copper.hat edited question.

Comment: I rolled your edit back, since you shouldn't really copy an answer and put it in your post- it makes it confusing for people who will find your post and read it. I've put it in an acceptable format for the site.

Comment: @cmk Okey, I understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem! $ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Munkres specifies that if $A$ is $n\times m$, then $$|A|=\max\{|a_{ij}|: {1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m}\}.$$ Continuing from where you were, we can see that for an arbitrary entry of $AB$, say $(AB)_{ij},$ $$\left| \sum ^{m}_{k=1}a_{ik}b_{kj}\right|\leq \sum ^{m}_{k=1}\left |a_{ik}b_{kj}\right |\leq |A|\sum ^{m}_{k=1}\left |b_{kj}\right |\leq m|A||B|.$$ Since that was an arbitrary element of $AB,$ we can conclude that the same holds for the max over $i$ and $j$.